# How to improve the efficiency of integer sidelength right triangle generator?

Tags: java

I'm looking to decrease the runtime of my code. I'm trying to solve [problem 75](https://projecteuler.net/problem=75) at Project Euler, where I have to find all integer combinations of side lengths that yield a right triangle such that its perimeter is less than or equal to 1.5 million. My code to perform this is below.

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Problem_75 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        double c = 0;
        for(int L = 1; L<= 1500000; L++){
            outerloop:
            for(int a = 1; a <= L-2; a++){
                for(int b = 1; b < L-a; b++){
                    c = Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b);
                    if((10*c)%10 == 0){
                        count++;
                        break outerloop;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

How would I go about decreasing the time it takes for this program to run to completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a Project Euler problem....so that should be a *huge* hint that there is a mathematical formula out there to solve it. In this case, what you are looking for is a way to generate Pythagorean Triplets. Here are several ways to do it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples

I highly recommend using either Euclid's formula or the Fibonacci method, but all of them seem to be doable. Basically the point is to avoid using nested for loops and testing every single combination of `a` and `b` lengths in a naive way. Math formulas are the way to go.

Comment: Are all possible triples in my range generated this way? I see that only Dickson's method states that all triples can be found, and that Fibonacci's method doesn't generate all primitive triples.

Comment: @onetoinfinity True, I didn't read that fibonacci method doesn't generate all primitive triples. But basically you can do it with a method that only generates all primitive triples. For example, Euclid's method will find (3,4,5) but then you can multiply that to get the non-primitives. So I would either use Dickson's to get them all or Euclid's with multiplying to get higher values. Just remember to store them in an implementation of the Set interface so you don't get duplicate wire lengths (like in the example on the Project Euler page, it shows 120 cm: (30,40,50), (20,48,52), (24,45,51)).

Comment: After all, the problem asks to count the total number of wire lengths possible, not exactly the number of triples. (though obviously this is done best through generating triples anyways)